# Apply style to child-views

Tags: android, styles

I am looking for a way to apply style to the childs of a tableLayout (tableRow and Textview), the same way we do in css:

```
.style > childElementType { properties ... }
```

I would like to achieve the same behavior with my android Styling, meaning that I want to change for instance child's backgrounds depending on their types.

Is it possible?

Thanks,
Antoine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pseudocode

> function {
>
> 1. **loop on all children**
> 2. **if(child.class=="classname") -> set Style**
>
> }

Comment: There no View.setStyle method. So the answer is wrong